# Can't run Vagrant commands

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtual-machine

I got this error when trying to run `vagrant up` on Windows 7 to initialize VM. I got the Directory not empty problem when I ran other Vagrant commands, so I can't do anything to set up my VM. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1444:in `rmdir': Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - C:/Users/Vu/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant20160421-5284-idj4q2 (Errno::ENOTEMPTY)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1444:in `block in remove_dir1'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1458:in `platform_support'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1443:in `remove_dir1'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1436:in `remove'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:778:in `block in remove_entry'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1493:in `ensure in postorder_traverse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1493:in `postorder_traverse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:776:in `remove_entry'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tmpdir.rb:94:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:128:in `fs_case_sensitive?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:145:in `fs_real_path'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:121:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:165:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:165:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try to remove all files in Temp dir and reboot your system or use system disk cleaner.